# Scriptaculous - setStyle not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm attempting to adjust some elements on a page dynamically when it gets resized (or opened on smaller displays).  There is a piece of code that looks roughly like this:

```
$('some_id').setStyle({'margin-left':'200px'});
```

And it works as intended in Chrome but is failing in Firefox with no JavaScript warning or errors.  And to be clear I have inspected the element in Firefox.  It's straight up just not getting the style set.  If I manually add in this rule with the inspector it works as intended.

More code has been requested:

```
function reset_ad_size() {
    topAlign($('leftColumn'), $('adContentLeftFloat'));
    leftSide = leftAlign($('mainBodyFrame'), $('adContentLeftFloat'));
    leftSide -= 190;

    if(leftSide < 0) {
        $('site_wrap_neo').setStyle({'margin-left':'200px'});
        leftSide = 5;
    }
    $('adContentLeftFloat').setStyle({left:leftSide+'px'});
}

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  reset_ad_size();
  window.onresize = function() {
    reset_ad_size();
  }
});
```

Comment: I've edited the post with an update to the code.

Comment: JavaScript is enabled and I mean when you right click and say "Inspect element with Firebug".  It's called the inspector in Chrome, methinks.  But yeah -- when I manually add in that rule in Firebug (the margin-left), then it appears to render properly.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem and wound up fixing it with this:

```
$('site_wrap_neo').style.marginLeft='200px';
```

For whatever reason Firefox didn't like the setStyle from Scriptaculous on that.

Comment: to use `setStyle()` correctly you need to use the camel case. `$('site_wrap_neo').setStyle({'marginLeft':'200px'})`